# Is it a good idea to place the Power Supply Unit Below the Hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, desktop-computer

Several years ago I bought a new computer casing which is very weird. Its small and compact. Normally, we have the PSU in the top. But in here, the PSU is on the bottom and right below the hard drive. Recently, two of my hard drives started to show problems. Read errors and bad sectors. Can it be the PSU and the design of the casing?

Here's an image of the PSU and the hard drive :

[image: Here's an image of the PSU and the hard drive :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PC (which is a cooler master which is, IMO a good/respectable make) has the PSU on the bottom and I've not had any issues. Also, at the bottom of my case (under the PSU) is a grill to allow air flow.

I think the key thing is if the box is well ventilated (or not). Ensure you have fans blowing on the hard drives (mine are at front of case) and that it's not hot inside. If you have a small factor case, you may be limited on how many fans can be powered (and also the motherboard will limit this due to how many headers you have for fans).

Comment: My PSU fan is facing the floor. The case have a gap for it to pass air. But its not possible to place any fans below the disks because there's only a very small gap between the disks and the power supply unit. The rare vents of the PSU are directed at the disks!

Comment: Just attached an image of the PSU and the hard drive. Does you one also look like this?

Comment: No as my fan blows out into the grill. If you're worried, buy a smaller factor PSU to increase the gap between the PSU and hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of cases do it these days. The 'traditional' layout with the PSU on top was designed to draw in air and blow it into the processor to help the processor heatsink and fan (as counterintuitive as it seems) - modern systems run cooler, have additional fans, generally, cool the system efficiently enough that the warm PSU air isn't really needed.

The bottom PSU simply draws in air and blows it out to cool itself.

Now, working out why your drives are failing isn't that hard. You're already looking at the SMART information on the drive I hope - check what the maximum heat on them is - overheating can cause problems. Look at the age of the drives and age related variables. And well.. drives fail.

I'd guess overall its probably *not* the PSU

Comment: To further this, I would suggest  you download http://www.acronis.co.uk/homecomputing/products/drive-monitor/ as it is free and will let you know disc live etc, and temp.

Comment: Just attached an image of the PSU and the hard drive. According to smart data, One drive is 33 C and the other one is 36 degrees Celsius. Seems to be normal right?

Comment: It would alert you if it was too hot!

Comment: ya, mine run in the 40s. That *is* the strangest case layout I've seen I'd say

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this case is designed so that the PSU draws in cool air from the front of the case and is supposed to expel warm air out the bottom, except that the PSU in the picture is an older style that has a vent on the side where the wires come out.

That's likely going to be causing problems.  You *have* to have a PSU with an intake on its bottom and outlet at the back *only* - and the PSU must have its own fan.

I realise this is an incredibly old question but I came here looking for answers in 2022 and others may too.  Bonus points for nostalgia - the all bare metal case interior!